# How to insert another column values in a column with their respective location?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

```
a=data["Col2"]
a=a.dropna()
a=pd.DataFrame(a)
k=[]
for i in data["Col1"]:
  k.append(i)
o=1
for i in a.index:
  o=o+i
  k.insert(o,a['COLOR2'][i])
  o+=1
```

But the problem here is the index of Col1 changes after 1st insertion.
And after adding 1(`o+=1`), it still does not give the desired output.

Comment: There is multiple columns? Ouput is one column `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need new one column `DataFrame` from columns `Col1, Col2` use:

```
df = data[['Col1','Col2']].stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Col')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **counter initialized to 1,**  such as -

```
a=data["Col2"]
a=a.dropna()
a=pd.DataFrame(a)
k=[]
for i in data["Col1"]:
  k.append(i)

counter=1

for i in a.index:
  o=i+counter
  k.insert(o,a['Col2'][i])

  counter+=1
```